# Executing a command after the first command executed

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I just recently installed beep on Ubuntu and finally managed to get it to work.
So I was able to hear the beeping sound after executing:

```
beep
```

Everything worked well, however, I was just wondering if it's possible to execute "beep" everytime I execute a command. Say for example:

```
cat /etc/passwd && beep
```

After reading /etc/passwd, it will be executing a beeping sound. I'd like to know if there's a way to execute beep after every command without having me to use "&& beep" always.

A clearer example:

```
ls && beep
ls -la && beep
cat /etc/passwd && beep
```

Notice the constant command "beep" followed by "&&" after every initial command.

Comment: If there is anybody within earshot, I hope you are using headphones.

Comment: Or some *very* heavy armor.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `PROMPT_COMMAND=beep` (try it first, then add to your `~/.bashrc` if it doesn't drive you crazy). This will execute `beep` just before it displays the command prompt.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It worked flawlessly.
"beep" was just a test for these kinds of processes. I shall use your resource for other commands in mind. Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try altering your prompt:

```
PS1="$PS1"'\007'
```